# Can I create a Druid lookup using time as a dimension?

Tags: lookup, druid

I am able to build lookups like

```
  {
"type":"lookup",
"dimension":"type",
"outputName":"type_name",
"outputType": "STRING",
"retainMissingValue":true,
"lookup":{"type": "map", "map":
{"0": "Unknown",
"1": "Mobile(Other)",
"2": "Desktop/Notebook", 
"3": "Connected/Smart TV", 
"4": "Mobile Phone"}, 
"isOneToOne":true}
}
```

However, I would like to create one using the time of day as the input variable. Is there any way to do so without having to add hour to the datasource as a dimension? For example, the hours 5am-9am should map to morning etc. I am running druid 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works! You can also add a timezone which is important if your data is in UTC like ours.

```
{
  "type": "extraction",
  "dimension": "__time",
  "outputName": "hourOfDay",
  "extractionFn": {
    "type": "cascade",
    "extractionFns": [
      {
        "type": "timeFormat",
        "format": "H",
        "locale": "en"
      },
      {
        "type": "lookup",
        "lookup": {
          "type": "map",
          "map": {
            "0": "early_morning",
            "1": "early_morning",
            "2": "early_morning",
            "3": "early_morning",
            "4": "early_morning",
            "5": "early_morning",
            "6": "morning",
            "7": "morning",
            "8": "morning",
            "9": "morning",
            "10": "morning",
            "11": "morning",
            "12": "afternoon",
            "13": "afternoon",
            "14": "afternoon",
            "15": "afternoon",
            "16": "afternoon",
            "17": "evening",
            "18": "evening",
            "19": "evening",
            "20": "evening",
            "21": "night",
            "22": "night",
            "23": "night"
          }
        },
        "retainMissingValue": true,
        "injective": true
      }
    ]
  }
```